# Can I have two versions of the framework in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I am working on iOS app, and I got two versions of some `CustomLib.framework` from another team: one only supports real iOS devices and another only supports simulators.
For instance, after I integrated "simulator version" of the framework into my app and build for real device, I got an error:

> Could not find module 'CustomLib' for target 'arm64-apple-ios'; found:
>   i386, x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64, i386-apple-ios-simulator

It is very inconvenient to remove/reintegrate these frameworks into the Xcode project when I want to switch between device ands simulator builds.

What is the correct way to insert them both into the project and let compiler smartly choose the correct one when building for device or for simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this via:

```
Project -> Build Settings -> Search Paths
```

[image]